# Create new conditional string variable in R that is a paste() of existing string variables

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a problem with R that is driving me crazy....

I set a lot of conditional variables based on reported data (cleaning and validation) and run into this all the time. It has to do with the length of replacement vectors in combination with conditional statements (excuse my poor explanation...).

Let me run an example by you:

Based on reported data I create a "synthetic" character variable `batch_id` as follows `paste(var1, var2, sep="")`. However, only when `var2` is 6 characters long AND ends in a "B".

If var2 is shorter (which it often is) or does not end in "B" I want `batch_id <- NA` (missing)

I tried with the following:

`data <- within(data, batch_id[nchar(data$var2) <6] <- NA)`

`data <- within(data, batch_id[nchar(data$var2) == 6 &
         !substr(data$var2, 6, 6) == "B"] <- NA)`

`data <- within(
         data, batch_id[nchar(data$var2) == 6 &
         substr(data$var2, 6, 6) == "B"] <- paste(data$var1, data$var2, sep=""))`

However, on the last line of code I get the error message :

`number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

Oooh, how I love this error message !! :)

I know that by setting the same condition `[...]` on the right hand side for **both** `var1` and `var2` it actually works, but there must be a better (more elegant and more readable later on) way of doing this ??

Comment: This question would benefit from a reproducible example.

Comment: `data$var1 <- c('1234','123', '4353')`  `data$var2 <- c('02342', '123456', '12345B')`  would work.

Comment: I suggest you incorporate that in your question, along with the desired result.

Comment: Assuming the desired result is `c(NA,NA,"435312345B")` (which is hopefully the case), the one-liner in my answer does the job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend:

```
batch_id = ifelse(grepl("B$",data$var2) & nchar(data$var2)==6, 
                             paste(data$var1, data$var2, sep=""), NA)
```

Does everything in one line, and avoids the complexity of adding additional libraries and learning how to use them... what's not to love?!

Answer (score 3):

```
data$batch_id <- paste(data$var1, data$var2, sep="")
```

And afterwards you can change values to NA according to your conditions.

Comment: Wow! [head on table] Talk about backwards thinking. That avoids the whole problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
library(stringr)

# generate some dummy data
df <- data.frame(var1=c("a", "b", "c"), var2=c("12345B", "123B", "123456"),stringsAsFactors=F)


df$batch_id <- with(df, ifelse(nchar(var2) == 6 & str_sub(var2, -1) == "B", str_c(var1, var2), NA))
```

Comment: Elegant. I'll try it out. Haven't tried `stringr` yet, maybe it's time

Comment: `?grep`, `?grepl` and `?gsub` are the way to go if you haven't met them before...

Comment: If you want to go for `grepl` then `with(df, ifelse(grepl("?????B$", var2), paste0(var1, var2), NA))` would be even shorter

Comment: Shorter, but unfortunately no longer correct. `grepl("^.{5}B$",var2)` works, but is much trickier to explain to the OP, who's already familiar with `nchar`. Simplicity of code is a better goal than just minimising the number of characters.